# can't draw a polyline on google maps v3, but can draw the points of it as markers (I am using OpenStreetMap layer)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap, polyline

the following code is used to draw a `polyline` on Google Maps using `V3 API`, but sometimes is draws the `polyline` and most of times doesn't despite there are point (as I can show the points on the map as markers) but no `polyline` appears

**update 2** : I am using `openstreetmap` layer over `Google maps`. does that cause the problem when drawing the `polyilne` ?

`w` variable contains data as string , for example :

```
w= 35.1212,55.2333\n36.32366,56.3333
```

Real data sample for `w` : [this code can draw markers for the following points but can't draw a polyline ]

```
34.440501,31.515222
34.441933,31.514346
34.44247,31.514013
34.442603,31.51394
34.443607,31.513423
34.4445,31.512926
34.444762,31.512772
34.445186,31.512523
34.445257,31.512481
34.445311,31.512449
34.445614,31.512264
34.446244,31.511867
34.446939,31.511429
34.447351,31.511193
34.448081,31.512174
34.448241,31.512357
34.448576,31.512741
34.449147,31.513185
34.4499,31.513723
34.450894,31.514401
34.451925,31.515362
34.452905,31.516176
34.454194,31.517266
34.455337,31.518236
34.456215,31.51898
34.456987,31.519646
34.457583,31.520166
34.458298,31.520772
34.458989,31.52139
34.459659,31.521959
34.460476,31.522653
34.461192,31.523228
34.461869,31.523788
34.46256,31.524376
34.463302,31.525015
34.464062,31.525668
34.464433,31.525986
34.464737,31.526246
34.465247,31.526683
34.465498,31.526907
34.466666,31.52792
34.46722,31.528404
34.467327,31.528495
34.468014,31.529081
34.468379,31.52939
34.469296,31.530177
34.469771,31.530583
34.470152,31.53091
34.470951,31.531597
34.471617,31.532172
34.472388,31.532838
34.472664,31.533076
34.47295,31.533397
34.473422,31.533653
34.474028,31.534065
34.474844,31.534629
34.475725,31.535253
34.476083,31.535517
34.476697,31.535947
34.477105,31.536209
34.477627,31.536477
34.478,31.536742
34.478398,31.536989
34.478935,31.537325
34.480044,31.537975
34.480985,31.538529
34.481362,31.53878
34.481416,31.538819
34.482407,31.539419
34.482682,31.539109
34.483132,31.538603
34.483341,31.538368
34.483917,31.537753
34.484202,31.537449
34.484288,31.537357
34.484944,31.536587
34.485118,31.536383
34.485205,31.536304
34.485648,31.535903
34.485984,31.535598
34.486246,31.535381
34.486445,31.535291
34.486533,31.535254
34.486607,31.535282
34.486706,31.535354
34.486869,31.535526
34.487012,31.535692
34.487212,31.535923
34.487273,31.536006
34.487767,31.53571
34.488336,31.535395
34.48883,31.535148
34.489078,31.535032
34.489354,31.534901
34.48955,31.534788
34.489756,31.535011
34.489831,31.535097
34.490268,31.534748
34.49065,31.534473
34.490857,31.53436
34.491044,31.534319
34.491352,31.534248
34.491458,31.534237
34.491548,31.534304
34.491879,31.534209
34.492227,31.534203
34.492457,31.534214
34.492042,31.533636
34.492162,31.533542
```

*note : I have reversed `lng` and `lat` when creating a point for some purpose*

where `a` is array that has the points to represent as a polyine 
code

---

```
var mypolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                    strokeOpacity: .6,
                    strokeWeight: 3,
                    clickable: true
                    });

                    //  var bounds2 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                        var a=w.split("\n");

                        for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
                        {
                            var zz=a[i].split(",");
                            var lat=zz[0];
                            var lng=zz[1];
                            var path = [];
                            var path = mypolyline.getPath();
                            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lng),parseFloat(lat));
                            createMarker(i,name,point,icon[1],2);
                        //  alert(path.length);
                            path.push(point);
                            mypolyline.setPath(path);
                           mypolyline.setMap(map);
                        }
```

CreateMarker() function

```
function createMarker(id,name,point,icon,type) {
   //  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(point, customIcons[type]);

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
                icon: icon
            });


         markersArray.push(marker);

         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',  function() {  


          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({  content: name  }); 
          infowindow.open(map, marker); 
          map.panTo(point);
          });
  return marker;
  }
```

Comment: What's the contents of 'w'?  Can you add the code from createMarker?  I don't understand why you're swapping around lat and lng - that's bound to lead to problems.

Comment: if createMarker is exist or NOT , is doesn't affect anything

Answer (score 0):

So you create an array, then you ignore that and recreate it as an MVCArray using the getPath() function.  Get rid of the first line (this isn't the cause of the problems though).

```
var path = [];
var path = mypolyline.getPath();
```

Just a thought - is the path a required attribute when you first create the polyline?

It seems to me that you initially create the mypolyline without any path.  So when you then do this on the first iteration, it's not going to work, because all you're passing to .setPath() is one point, but I assume a path can only work when there's at least 2 points.

```
path.push(point);
mypolyline.setPath(path);
```

**Update:** I think the thing to do would be to just start out with an empty array, loop over your coordinates adding them into the array.  Then after the loop, create the polyline, rather than trying to update it each time you iterate over the loop.  For instance:

```
var a=w.split("\n");

var path = [];

for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    var zz=a[i].split(",");
    var lat=zz[0];
    var lng=zz[1];
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lng),parseFloat(lat));
    createMarker(i,name,point,icon[1],2);
    path.push(point);
}

var mypolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
    map: map,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: .6,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    clickable: true
});
```

Comment: I have tried to remove path attribute, but the same problem !!

Comment: The same problem ,I want to tell you that I am using openstreetmap layer over google maps ..